# selenium won't get URL?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

this my code open fire fox and get google

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class auto {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "//root//Desktop//jarselenium//geckodriver-v0.20.1-linux64/geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        //driver.get("https://www.easybooking.lk/login");
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

but when i run this code selenium open fire fox but wont get url  im running this code in linux

Comment: I doubt that would be the problem, but try replacing `//` by `/` in your webdriver path.

Comment: its open Firefox but its not get url :(

Comment: i have no idea and i have another problem when i enable  //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS); this line i got error

Comment: its the problem is my os is Kali Linux and Mozilla version is 52.2.0

Comment: yep when i try same think in windows its works perfect

Comment: my  selenium  is Java  3.11.0  and  Mozilla GeckoDriver  0.20.0

Comment: thz but my selenium version is  3.11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the current implementation of *Selenium v3.11.0*, *GeckoDriver 0.20.1* I don't see any major issue in your code block perhaps the trace logs would have helped us to understand your issue better. Having said that you need to follow the below mentioned steps :

- As you are using *Linux based System* you need to pass the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* within single forward slashes i.e. `/` as follows :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/root/Desktop/jarselenium/geckodriver-v0.20.1-linux64/geckodriver");
  ```
- As *GeckoDriver* opens *Firefox Browser* client in maximized mode you need to omit the line of code :

  ```
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  ```

Comment: thank but i did this now same problem its open Firefox and maximize  but driver.get("https://www.google.com"); this line is not working :(

Comment: It's in a main, not in a test class. You should remove `Execute your @Test as a non-root user.`

Comment: @TwiN You spotted it right :) I have a habit of answering both the `main()` as well as the `TestNG` tests so I use a _mainNG_ notation

Comment: @sanjan I think you are trying to run away too fast, your issue is with the line `driver.manage().window().maximize();` you are lucky to escape a `InvalidArgumentException`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:08.638Z'
System info: host: 'GHOST', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.0-kali4-amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: 
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: @sanjan Please please please don't try to overspeed. Perform the steps as per my answer one by one. Your _JDK_ version is **ancient** and **outdated** as per **Step 1**

Comment: Upgrade Firefox version to Firefox v59.0.2 levels. here is my problem my fire fox verson is 52.2.0

Comment: Downgrade _GeckoDriver_ then.